# preg_grep does not show result with double quotes(")

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes

My code is as follows:

```
 $escapedOperator = ":";
 $operator['symbol'] = ":";
 $string = 'title: "space before" and text breaks';
 if(count(preg_grep('/\w["]*\s*'.$escapedOperator.'\s*["]*\w/',$string))){
       $search = "/\s*".$escapedOperator."\s*/";
       $string = preg_replace($search,$operator['symbol'],$string); 
 }else{
       $string=str_replace($operator['symbol'],"",$string);                 
 }
```

I am getting output:

```
title "space before" and text breaks
```

But I need:

```
title:"space before" and text breaks
```

Comment: `preg_grep` takes an array as second parameter, not a string. Perhaps are you looking for `preg_match`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `preg_grep()` requires an array as a second parameter, rather than a string.  If you change your:

`$string = 'title: "space before" and text breaks';`

To:

`$string = array('title: "space before" and text breaks');`

Your code works, and `echo $string[0];`, will output `title:"space before" and text breaks`

If the objective is to just remove whitespace around the colon (:), then could you not just do this?

```
$string = 'title: "space before" and text breaks';
$string = preg_replace('/\s*:\s*/', ":", $string);
echo $string[0];
```

This will also output `title:"space before" and text breaks`